# Optimizing a script that lists available commands with manual pages

Tags: bash, optimization

I'm using this script to generate a list of the available commands with manual pages on the system. Running this with `time` shows an average of about 49 seconds on my computer.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

for x in $(for f in $(compgen -c); do which $f; done | sort -u); do 
    dir=$(dirname $x)
    cmd=$(basename $x) 
    if [[ ! $(man --path "$cmd" 2>&1) =~ 'No manual entry' ]]; then 
        printf '%b\n' "${dir}:\n${cmd}"
    fi
done | awk '!x[$0]++'
```

Is there a way to optimize this for faster results?

This is a small sample of my current output. The goal is to group commands by directory. This will later be fed into an array.

```
/bin:    # directories generated by $dir
[        # commands generated by $cmd (compgen output)
cat
chmod
cp
csh
date
```

Answer (score 0):

Going for a complete disregard of built-ins here. That's what `which` does, anyway. Script not thoroughly tested.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob # need this for "empty" checks below
MANPATH=${MANPATH:-/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man}
IFS=: # chunk up PATH and MANPATH, both colon-deliminated

# just look at the directory!
has_man_p() {
    local needle=$1 manp manpp result=()
    for manp in $MANPATH; do
        # man? should match man0..man9 and a bunch of single-char things
        # do we need 'man?*' for longer suffixes here?
        for manpp in "$manp"/man?; do
            # assumption made for filename formats. section not checked.
            result=("$manpp/$needle".*)
            if (( ${#result[@]} > 0 )); then
                return 0
            fi
        done
    done
    return 1
}

unset seen
declare -A seen # for deduplication
for p in $PATH; do
    printf '%b:\n' "$p" # print the path first
    for exe in "$p"/*; do
        cmd=${exe##*/}  # the sloppy basename
        if [[ ! -x $exe || ${seen[$cmd]} == 1 ]]; then
            continue
        fi
        seen["$cmd"]=1
        if has_man_p "$cmd"; then
            printf '%b\n' "$cmd"
        fi
    done
done
```

Time on Cygwin with a truncated PATH (the full one with Windows has too many misses for the original version):

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
$ time (sh ./opti.sh &>/dev/null)

real    0m3.577s
user    0m0.843s
sys     0m2.671s

$ time (sh ./orig.sh &>/dev/null)

real    2m10.662s
user    0m20.138s
sys     1m5.728s
```

(Caveat for both versions: most stuff in Cygwin's `/usr/bin` comes with a `.exe` extension)